# Use OData schema exposed by .NET in iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, .net, odata, odata4j

Here is our case:

We exposed some POCO types using *OData* by *ASP.NET Web api*, mainly the schema of models. What we want to achieve is **share these schema with iOS and Android clients**. I am not familiar with both iOS and Android developments, isthere any methods let us develop just like normal .NET application style, add something like `ServiceReference` to the project, so that we can use those models? Or some other ways to allow make use of those stuffs.

We just focused on latest version of iOS (iOS 7 / iOS 8), and Android 4.4+. Any shared experience is welcome.

Comment: Were you able to build ODataCpp library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following libraries are both for OData V4 only.

For iOS, there is the [ODataCpp](https://github.com/odata/odatacpp) library owned by the same team who implements the ASP.NET Web API OData at Microsoft that you can try out. It's recently open sourced and will have its first binary release soon. It supports iOS as a target building platform and [iOS apps can be built using it](https://github.com/OData/odatacpp/wiki/1.2-Create-an-iOS-client-app-in-Xcode).

For Android, there is the [Apache Olingo](http://olingo.apache.org/support.html) Java Client. It's still under development but according to the recent communications on developer mailing list, its first V4 client release will be very soon. You can have access to the source code on it's [Git repository](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=olingo-odata4-js.git;a=summary). It's been tested for building Android applications.

Comment: ODataCpp is not building correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937701/failing-to-build-odatacppclient-for-ios-cant-find-files

Answer (score 0):

Also, while not a server side native application, a strong stop gap is the library Odata4js, which allows you to Prototype PlainObject Models, and use data-driven js libraries to manipulate/work with the data.  Javascript would work on both platforms until official APIs release, and OData4Js works very well with other major releases such as Angular, jQuery, etc.