# Failing to build ODataCppClient for iOS, can't find files

Tags: ios, odata

I need to use Odata in one of my project. I found the latest OData open source at https://github.com/OData/odatacpp-client but I could not build it successfully for iOS.

I ran following commands as mentioned in README.md:

```
cd odatacpp
mkdir lib
cd lib
git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/casablanca
cd casablanca
git checkout v2.1.0
mkdir build.release
cd build.release
cmake ../Release -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make -j 4

cd ../../..
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug # replace 'Debug' with 'Release' if needed
make -j 4
```

It failed after I ran following commands:

```
cd lib/casablanca/Build_iOS
./configure.sh
```

Error logs from console:

```
srayabharapu:odatacpp-client-master <currentUser>$ cd lib/casablanca/Build_iOS
srayabharapu:Build_iOS <currentUser>$ ./configure.sh
Cloning into 'OpenSSL-for-iPhone'...
remote: Counting objects: 43, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (37/37), done.
remote: Total 43 (delta 1), reused 33 (delta 1)
Unpacking objects: 100% (43/43), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
~/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/OpenSSL-for-iPhone ~/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS
Downloading openssl-1.0.1j.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 4329k  100 4329k    0     0   811k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:-- 1025k
Building openssl-1.0.1j for iPhoneSimulator 8.1 i386
Please stand by...
Building openssl-1.0.1j for iPhoneSimulator 8.1 x86_64
Please stand by...
Building openssl-1.0.1j for iPhoneOS 8.1 armv7
Please stand by...
Building openssl-1.0.1j for iPhoneOS 8.1 armv7s
Please stand by...
Building openssl-1.0.1j for iPhoneOS 8.1 arm64
Please stand by...
    Build library...
Building done.
Cleaning up...
Done.
~/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS
Cloning into 'boostoniphone'...
remote: Counting objects: 106, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (100/100), done.
remote: Total 106 (delta 50), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (106/106), 83.04 MiB | 752.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (50/50), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
~/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone ~/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS
Cleaning everything before we start to build...

    =================================================================
    Done

Updating boost into /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/boost...
Cloning into '/Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/boost'...
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
./boost.sh: line 88: pushd: /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/boost: No such file or directory
./boost.sh: line 89: ./bootstrap.sh: No such file or directory
./boost.sh: line 90: ./b2: No such file or directory
~/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS

    =================================================================
    Done

BOOST_VERSION:     1.55.0
BOOST_LIBS:        random thread filesystem regex locale system
BOOST_SRC:         /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/boost
IOSBUILDDIR:       /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/ios/build
OSXBUILDDIR:       /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/osx/build
PREFIXDIR:         /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/ios/prefix
IOSFRAMEWORKDIR:   /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/ios/framework
OSXFRAMEWORKDIR:   /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/osx/framework
IPHONE_SDKVERSION: 7.0
XCODE_ROOT:        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
COMPILER:          clang++

Invent missing headers
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
./boost.sh: line 112: cd: /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/boost: No such file or directory
Bootstrapping (with libs random,thread,filesystem,regex,locale,system)
./boost.sh: line 115: ./bootstrap.sh: No such file or directory

    =================================================================
    Done

./boost.sh: line 123: cd: /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/boost: No such file or directory
./boost.sh: line 125: /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/boost/tools/build/src/user-config.jam: No such file or directory
./boost.sh: line 134: ./bjam: No such file or directory
./boost.sh: line 135: ./bjam: No such file or directory

    =================================================================
    Done

./boost.sh: line 138: /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/boost/tools/build/src/user-config.jam: No such file or directory
Building for simulator...
./boost.sh: line 147: ./bjam: No such file or directory

    =================================================================
    Done

Building for osx...
./boost.sh: line 151: ./b2: No such file or directory

    =================================================================
    Done

Splitting all existing fat binaries...
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a: No such file or directory
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a: No such file or directory
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_locale.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_locale.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_locale.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_locale.a: No such file or directory
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_locale.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_locale.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_system.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_system.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_system.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_system.a: No such file or directory
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_system.a (No such file or directory)
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_system.a (No such file or directory)
Decomposing each architecture's .a files
Decomposing libboost_random.a...
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
Decomposing libboost_thread.a...
ar: ../libboost_thread.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_thread.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_thread.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_thread.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_thread.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_thread.a: No such file or directory
Decomposing libboost_filesystem.a...
ar: ../libboost_filesystem.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_filesystem.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_filesystem.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_filesystem.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_filesystem.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_filesystem.a: No such file or directory
Decomposing libboost_regex.a...
ar: ../libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
Decomposing libboost_locale.a...
ar: ../libboost_locale.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_locale.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_locale.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_locale.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_locale.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_locale.a: No such file or directory
Decomposing libboost_system.a...
ar: ../libboost_system.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_system.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_system.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_system.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_system.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_system.a: No such file or directory
Linking each architecture into an uberlib ( libboost_random.a libboost_thread.a libboost_filesystem.a libboost_regex.a libboost_locale.a libboost_system.a => libboost.a )
rm: /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/ios/build/*/libboost.a: No such file or directory
...armv7
ar: obj/*.o: No such file or directory
...armv7s
ar: obj/*.o: No such file or directory
...arm64
ar: obj/*.o: No such file or directory
...i386
ar: obj/*.o: No such file or directory
rm: /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/osx/build/*/libboost.a: No such file or directory
...osx-i386
ar: obj/*.o: No such file or directory
...x86_64
ar: obj/*.o: No such file or directory
Framework: Building /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/ios/framework/boost.framework from /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/ios/build...
Framework: Setting up directories...
Framework: Creating symlinks...
Lipoing library into /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/ios/framework/boost.framework/Versions/A/boost...
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: empty archive with no architecture specification: /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/ios/build/arm64/libboost.a (can't determine architecture for it)

Aborted: Lipo /Users/<currentUser>/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/ios/framework failed
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, please let us know.

Comment: I have edited my question with what I have done and error I'm getting.

Comment: It's should be a network issue during cloning boost for ios. Can you try the build again?

Answer (score 1):

> Cloning into
>   '/Users//Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/boost'...
>   error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200 fatal: The remote end
>   hung up unexpectedly fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
>   ./boost.sh: line 88: pushd:
>   /Users//Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS/boostoniphone/boost:
>   No such file or directory ./boost.sh: line 89: ./bootstrap.sh: No such
>   file or directory ./boost.sh: line 90: ./b2: No such file or directory
>   ~/Downloads/odatacpp-client-master/lib/casablanca/Build_iOS

It looks like your clone of the remote repository did not complete successfully.  Everything after that is likely fallout from your not having that content available (eg: missing file, etc)

Comment: I did correct this, but now failing ecause of missing libcpprest.a.

Comment: which would be a completely different problem and would thus require a new question with specific details if you want further help from someone.